# How to capture the data from this dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multiple-fields-contact-form) bootsnipp for BootStrap.JS to create dynamic fields.

How can I capture the data from these dynamic fields as key value pairs?

And what if I have 2 sections on the same page that require these set of dynamic fields?

Any sample snippet would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed one fatal flaw about this snippet is that there's no way to differentiate multiple instances of a field. If you enter 2 phone numbers, which one is which? I guess the data could be sorted out server side, but I'm just front end and no very little about the magical realm of the back end.

I added a button `#data`, a hidden input `.cache`, and a function `collectData(ele)`. The HTML and jQuery are annotated with the details on function and purpose of each important component.

```
 //
/* collectData Function~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/ 
This function given a group of elements (in classic selector format) will assign each 
element the values of the closest fields as a unique name and the user entered value 
(if any.)
Use the console to see it gather data.
*/
        var collectData = function(ele) {
            var $tgt = $(ele);
            $tgt.each(function(index) {
// $tgt == $(this)
                var $fieldNames = $(this).next('.input-group-select-val').val();
                var $fieldValues=$(this).closest('.form-group').find('.form-control').val();

// Including index to each $fieldName in order to make each key/value pair unique.

                $(this).attr('name', $fieldNames+index);
                console.log('name: '+$(this).attr('name'));
                $(this).val($fieldValues);
                console.log('value: '+$(this).val());
              });
        }
```

**DEMO: http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/xaAXG**

Comment: And when I get back the data from the server as key value pairs, lets say in json format, how can we re-render the dynamic fields and set the values accordingly?

Comment: If you recall, I have informed you that I'm front-end, not back-end. Your OP requested any useful snippet that can extract the data from the fields of the form you provided for us. If you were to get the data from the server, you wouldn't want to throw them back into the inputs. Normally, say if the data is a response from an ajax post originating from our side (which would have to be another new question), you would have the JSON parsed and displayed in a new div.

Comment: agreed, but because it is a form, I need to provide the ability to update them as well. That is why I need a way to read json and put them back into the form.

Comment: Use ajax to send data, before it's sent convert with `JSON.stringify`, on the response from the server, use `parse.JSON` and store the parsed data with localStorage. Why would you want to muckup your inputs with processed data that should be stored elsewhere like a db? As you can tell, this process is not trivial and goes beyond the scope of OP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the selected li and get the text of it. I recommend adding value for every li but it is up to you afterall.I added id for your ul and checked it's action. The id i chose was "tryME" Anyway here is code you need:

```
$('#tryMe a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // This removes the class on selected li's
  $("#tryMe li").removeClass("select");

  // adds 'select' class to the parent li of the clicked element
  // 'this' here refers to the clicked a element
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('select');

  // sets the input field's value to the data value of the clicked a element
  $('#tryMe').val($(this).text());
  console.log( $('#tryMe').val());
});
```

here is your snip updated on bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/e3qqmab4SQ

Comment: I couldn't get anything in the console. https://zer00ne.tinytake.com/sf/NDc2NDMxXzI1NDkzMjc

Comment: i'l update my code as soon as possible. i'm on my way to home from work, but the answer of @zer00ne is working